# ExecuteWcFOperation http://www.microsoft... slow performance

Tags: external-content-type, performance, business-data-catalog

I am troubleshooting a performance issue and I see some log entries like:

> Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/MetadataObjectCreate). Execution Time=15111.6069221088

This being around the 15 second mark and the SharePoint server not having Internet access, this would seem to be a time out issue to me.

Is my assumption correct? And if it is, how do I stop SharePoint from doing this?